# Not entering thread method

Tags: java, multithreading

i am writing code from online to create a chat application. After trouble shooting my program to find out why it is not working I have discovered that the code inside my run method here is not being reached. here is the snippet of code

```
public void listen()
{
    listen = new Thread("Listen") {
        public void run()
        {
            writeMessage("Working in here");
            while (true) {
                String message = client.receive();
                if (message.startsWith("/c/")) {
                    client.setID(Integer.parseInt(message.substring(3, message.length())));
                    writeMessage("Successfully connected to server" + client.getID());
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

It is reaching the listen method itself, because if i use the write message command before i declare the thread, it prints out the message for me, any idea from looking at this why it will not enter any further?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Calling `start()` on your `Thread` would do it:

```
public void listen()
{
    listen = new Thread("Listen") {
        public void run()
        {
            writeMessage("Working in here");
            while (true) {
                String message = client.receive();
                if (message.startsWith("/c/")) {
                    client.setID(Integer.parseInt(message.substring(3, message.length())));
                    writeMessage("Successfully connected to server" + client.getID());
                }
            }
        }
    };
    listen.start(); // <-- Add this line
}
```

Also, you typically don't want to extend `Thread` (which you are doing here with an anonymous class). Usually you'll want to create a `Runnable` and pass that to `Thread`'s constructor instead:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // Do some work here
    }
};

Thread listen = new Thread(r, "Listen");
listen.start();
```

Or even better, use an `Executor`, there aren't many good reasons to create your own `Thread` objects.

Comment: you are correct in all but one detail - instead of start you need to execute run(). start() and run() do the same thing, only start() execute your thread sequentially i.e. in the same thread where you invoked it and run() actually starts a new thread where your code is executed

Comment: [That is incorrect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--).

Comment: @MichaelGantman no, you're wrong. start() iniciates a new thread and run() don't

Answer (score 0):

Certainly working with appropriate Execotor or even better ExecutorService is more appropriate way of working with threads today. Read about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). But if you insist on working the old way then you need to invoke `start()` method of your thread. Methods `start()` and `run()` do the same thing, only `run()` execute your thread sequentially i.e. in the same thread where you invoked it and `start()` actually starts a new thread where your code is executed which is what you wanted in the first place

Comment: Yep, I mixed start() and run() and didn't double-check it. It's been a while since I actually wrote on the level of Thread and Runnable. I use ExecutorService just like I recommended. No need to to be so smug though

Comment: Thanks, it is noted acknowledged and appreciated. Also, I edited my reply to be correct. So to anyone reading this and previous comment: the error was made in original response and now it is correct

Comment: Re, "Methods start() and run() do the same thing, only..."  That conveys a weak understanding of what methods are and what threads do.  Think of it this way:  Suppose I write a program, and my program contains a method named foobar().  Now, suppose you had the source code for my program open on the screen in front of you, and somebody asked you, "what does foobar() do?"  How would you answer that question?  OK.  Mick wrote a program (above) that contains a method named run().  How would you answer the question, "what does run() do?"